# Error Collection::appends does not exist In pagination with mapping

Tags: laravel-5, pagination

In my Laravel 5.8 app I have database request with mapping, like:

```
$paymentItems        = PaymentItem
    ::getByStatus('C', 'payments')
    ->select(
        $this->payment_items_tb . '.*',
        $this->downloads_tb . '.title as payed_item_title',
        $this->users_tb     . '.username as payment_username',
        $this->payments_tb . '.payment_type',
        ...
        $this->payments_tb . '.payer_shipping_address'
    )
    ->orderBy($this->payment_items_tb . '.created_at', 'desc')
    ->join($this->payments_tb, $this->payments_tb . '.id', '=', $this->payment_items_tb . '.payment_id')
    ->join($this->users_tb, $this->users_tb . '.id', '=', $this->payments_tb . '.user_id')
    ->join($this->downloads_tb, $this->downloads_tb . '.id', '=', $this->payment_items_tb . '.item_id')
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($item) {
        return [
            'id'               => $item->id,
            'total'            => $item->price * $item->quantity,
                ....
            'payment_type_label'     => Payment::getPaymentTypeLabel($item->payment_type),
        ];
    });
```

It worked ok for me untill I decided to remake this listing as pagination, like:

```
$paymentItems        = PaymentItem
    ::getByStatus('C', 'payments')
    ->select(
        $this->payment_items_tb . '.*',
        $this->downloads_tb . '.title as payed_item_title',
        $this->users_tb     . '.username as payment_username',
        $this->payments_tb . '.payment_type',
        ...
        $this->payments_tb . '.payer_shipping_address'
    )
    ->orderBy($this->payment_items_tb . '.created_at', 'desc')
    ->join($this->payments_tb, $this->payments_tb . '.id', '=', $this->payment_items_tb . '.payment_id')
    ->join($this->users_tb, $this->users_tb . '.id', '=', $this->payments_tb . '.user_id')
    ->join($this->downloads_tb, $this->downloads_tb . '.id', '=', $this->payment_items_tb . '.item_id')
    ->paginate($ref_items_per_pagination, null, null, $page)
    ->onEachSide((int)($ref_items_per_pagination / 2))

    ->map(function ($item) {
        return [
            'id'               => $item->id,
            'total'            => $item->price * $item->quantity,
            ...
            'payment_type_label'     => Payment::getPaymentTypeLabel($item->payment_type),
        ];
    });
```

But In my blade template I got error :

```
Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::appends does not exist. (View: /resources/views/defaultBS41Backend/admin/dashboard/payments_rows.blade.php) {"userId":5,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Method Illuminate\\Support\\Collection::appends does not exist. (View: /resources/views/defaultBS41Backend/admin/dashboard/payments_rows.blade.php) at /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.php:102, BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Method Illuminate\\Support\\Collection::appends does not exist.
```

trying to show pagination links block:

```
    <div class="row">
        {{ $paymentItems->appends([])->links() }}
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Refresh" onclick="javascript:backendDashboard.showPaymentsRows(1); return false;">
    </div>
```

Is there is a way to fix this error and to show paginations links ?